# Exiting App causes the image taken from gallery to go

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, imageurl

I am able to pull down images from my gallery and add them to image view but when I exit app and open it again image is gone. How do I save this image so that it stays there. Open gallery method:

```
  private void openimage() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGE_CODE);
    }
```

In onActionResult:

```
if (requestCode == IMAGE_CODE) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(contentURI));
            editor.commit();
            Glide.with(this).load(contentURI).into(imageView);

        }
```

As you can see I tried using shared preferences but it isnt wroking.
Any suggestions?

Comment: question is not clear, is you have problem settings image to navigation drawer or you not getting that image from `onActivityResult`

Comment: I got it but the images are coming back rotated for some reason. I edited my question

Comment: consider using image-loading libraries like (Glide or other) for loading image on result

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image URI on your shared preference